# ¿Dónde está instalado Sass en el entorno de desarrollo Homestead de Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, sass

Buenas, estoy empezando a aprender sobre Laravel, el framework de PHP, y he instalado la máquina virtual Homestead que ofrecen en su página para empezar a probar cosas rápidamente.
El caso es que tengo entendido que los proyectos de Laravel usan por defecto Sass para compilar los ficheros CSS, de hecho hay archivos scss en cada proyecto nuevo de Laravel, pero no encuentro Sass instalado en ninguna parte de la máquina virtual Homestead.
He probado a ejecutar el comando:

```
sass -v
```

Y el comando no se encuentra.
También he probado:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep sass
```

Investigué un poco más y me enteré de que sass depende de ruby, pero ni siquiera este paquete está instalado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para utilizar sass, se usa `elixir` (lo encontraras en `/gulpfile.js`)

Es muy simple, solo tienes que poner el archivo a compilar .

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});
```

e instalar gulp para manejarlo por nodejs

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, me ha ayudado a entender cómo maneja Laravel estas cosas.Ahora, en Laravel 5.5 esa funcionalidad me parece que cambia de nombre a Laravel Mix y el archivo a editar pasa a ser /webpack.mix.js.

Comment: Correcto, pero el uso es el mismo